# Problem when I try to save data in my database Django

Tags: python, django

I tried to make a pure api Django and save some data in my database for practicing.

But I have some problems when I try to save data.

For example

I tried this code for the post method

```
 def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = UpdateModelForm(self.request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=True)
            obj_data = obj.serialize()
            return self.render_to_response(obj_data, status=201)
        if form.errors:
            data = json.dumps(form.errors)
            return self.render_to_response(data, status=400)
        data = {"message": "Not Allowed"}
        return self.render_to_response(data, status=400)
```

And here is my Form validation

```
from django import forms


from .models import Update as UpdateModel


class UpdateModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UpdateModel
        fields = [
            'user',
            'content',
            'image'
        ]
```

And the model

```
class UpdateQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    #def serialize(self):
    #    qs = self
    #    return serialize('json', qs, fields=('user', 'content', 'image'))
    def serialize(self):
        list_values = list(self.values("user", "content", "image", "id"))
        return json.dumps(list_values)


class UpdateManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return UpdateQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)


# Create your models here.
class Update(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_update_image, blank=True, null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = UpdateManager()

    def __str__self(self):
        return self.content or ""

    def serialize(self):
        try:
            image = self.image.url
        except:
            image = ""
        data = {
            "id": self.id,
            "user": self.user,
            "content": self.content,
            "image": image
        }
        data_json = json.dumps(data)
        return data_json
```

My problem arises when I try to use the method, I get this dubious error.
What do you think it is?

```
{"user": ["Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices."]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with :

```
 data = {
        "id": self.id,
        "user": self.user.id,
        "content": self.content,
        "image": image
 }
```

*NB :* Pass the user ID instead of the user object.